# Getting the bounding rectangle of a drawString?

Tags: java, awt

Is there a way, given the current set font of the Graphics object and a String to get the bounding box that it would occupy?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer [`TextLayout#getBounds()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/font/TextLayout.html#getBounds%28%29); but if you already have a [`Graphics`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html) context, the string bounds methods of [`FontMetrics`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/FontMetrics.html) are convenient.